# How to do Authorization Using AWS V4 signature in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, authorization

I'm able to generate credentials using AWS sts assume role.
I have used AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder and AssumeRoleRequest class to generate the same.
However, I need to write a code to do authorization using AWS v4 signature. How Can I do it in Spring Boot / Java? Also, How can I pass the credentials to the POST request.

I found some articles where they show the below code. However, I'm not sure How to use it?

```
AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
        signer.setServiceName(Constant.SERVICE_NAME);
        signer.setRegionName(Constant.AWS_REGION);
        signer.presignRequest(request, new AWSCredentials() {
            
            @Override
            public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                return sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId();
            }
            
            @Override
            public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                return sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey();
            }
            
        }, sessionCredentials.getExpiration());
```

Can someone please help? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you think you need that? The Java AWS client SDK will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks, Erwin for your reply. I need to send a POST request to let's say "https:://abc.com" with a payload. How Can I send the post request by passing credentials(I have accesskey, secretkey, sessiontoken)?

Comment: That doesn't make clear why can't use the AWS client libraries. In any case, it depends on the HTTP client library that you're using. You need to make sure that all outgoing requests are signed. You can search for usages of AWS4Signer, this gives several good pointers in the first 20 examples: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Erwin. Are there any AWS client libraries you think I can make use of? According to you which HTTP client library should I use? I have used AWS4signer in my example above However not sure how to send a request